# Flutter change bottom nav bar height

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, navbar, safearea

I am trying to build a custom `bottomNavBar` and my code looks like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(scaleWidth(20)),
              topRight: Radius.circular(scaleWidth(20)),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                blurRadius: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: scaleWidth(59),
          child: Row(
            children: _buildBottomNavBarItems(context),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: AppColors.white,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

I am calling this inside a `Scaffold` like this:

```
bottomSheet: BottomNavBar(),
```

But the **problem** is that `bottomNavBar` is **covering the whole screen**! Without the `Column` it is working fine, but the `Column` is crucial so I can have the bottom `Container` with `height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,` so the `height` of the `navBar` is changing dynamically depending on the `SafeArea` of the device. (Example: iPhone SE has no `bottomSafeArea` but the iPhone X has one, so the height needs to be adjusted.)

What am I missing here and how can I solve this?

If you need any more info just let me know!

Comment: could you share the implementation of `scaleWidth(59)`?

Comment: @mightybruno that is not the issue, I am just resizing it depending on `MediaQuery.of(context)`. Ive tried it without, same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to the `Column`. Also, you don't need `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`, the bottom sheet is automatically aligned to the end.

Also, if you want `Scaffold.body` to take bottom widget's space into consideration, swap `bottomSheet` with `bottomNavigationBar`.

```
class Sheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        //...
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

https://www.dartpad.dev/374026cc206115bedf79925bb75720af?null_safety=true

Comment: thanks for your answer! I also changed it to `bottomNaviagtionBar` but how can I fill the safeArea space?

Comment: Isn't `SafeArea` widget what you're looking for? Try to wrap the `Column` with it https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html if not, you may want to take a look on `SafeArea.build` method implementation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea/build.html

Comment: working perfectly fine now, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bottomNavigationBar:` instead of `bottomSheet:` or in the body use `Stack:` and add the position of your bottomNavBar `bottom:0`